# Deploying Google Appengine on Windows

Tags: google, windows, google-app-engine

I have been using Linux (Ubuntu) for a long time and I am using the hosting on Google SQL cloud engine. I would like to move to Windows.

Steps to set it up on Linux were:

1. Download *go_appengine*
2. Write path to *.bashrc*
3. Go into the project folder and `appcfg.py update`.

I would like to start using Windows. What do I need to do? I can't find any guide which describes the process of pushing it on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

As per the official [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/tools/uploadinganapp), the recommend way to deploy a Go application onto Google App Engine is to use the `goapp deploy` command. The general guidelines to do so are listed in the provided link and here are the main steps for doing this on a Windows machine:

1. Download the App Engine SDK for Go from [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/download).
2. [Optionally] Specify `[YOUR_PROJECT_ID]` and `[YOUR_VERSION_ID]` in the app.yaml configuration file of your application.
3. Run the following command from within the root directory of your application:

`goapp deploy -application [YOUR_PROJECT_ID] -version [YOUR_VERSION_ID]`

Alternatively, it is also possible to use the appcfg tool to deploy a Go application by running the command `appcfg.py update` at step #3. More information about using this tool can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/tools/appcfg-arguments#update).